# Set the text in horizontal time line

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, annotatedtimeline

I am trying to implement horizontal timeline. SO I have written the code to design the horizontal line but I am able to figure out how I will write text on the above and below of the line.

One more thing I don't want to use any other library.

[image: Target ImageT]

I have try to solve it through Custom view as people here have been suggested but got struck.

timeline_segment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
       android:padding="3dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:text="Top"
        android:id="@+id/top_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@color/alphabet_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/circle1"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/alphabet_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

timeline_segment.java

```
public class timeline_segement extends LinearLayout {

    View rootView;
    TextView upperText;
    TextView startLine;
    TextView endLine;
    ImageView circleView;
    TextView bottomText;

    public timeline_segement(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public timeline_segement(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public timeline_segement(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }


    private void init(Context context) {

      rootView=inflate(context, R.layout.timeline_segment, this );

      upperText=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.top_data);
      bottomText=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_data);

      upperText.setText("Top");
      bottomText.setText("Bottom");

    }

    public  void setUpperText(String string)
    {
        upperText.setText(string);
    }

    public void setBottomText(String string)
    {
        bottomText.setText(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll need a custom view to achieve this. You can either composite ready-made views or go full custom.

Comment: can you provide me the link from where I can check the code.

Comment: well the timeline i guess it needs to be dynamically created, that means that every some time you will add a new bullet right? In this case you can create a view programmatically everytime you want to add a new view. That means that you will have to create a LinearLayout orientation vertical which will have 2 text view and 1 line.

Comment: ohk. thanks man I think I got the solution.

Comment: no problem...glad to be able to give at least a hint

Comment: hey @helldawg13.. can you have a look to my custom view and help me in figuring out what went wrong

Comment: Hey. I have figured out the error. thanks @KostasDrak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to answer because the comment box is kinda limiting. This is my comment:

> You'll need a custom view to achieve this. You can either composite ready-made views or go full custom

If you choose to composite views, then you start by breaking down that image level by level. At the highest level, its a horizontal layout with '`TimelineCell`'s (or whatever you choose to call it).

A `TimelineCell` will basically be a vertical `LinearLayout` with a right aligned `TextView`, a `View` that draws the line and another center aligned `TextView`.

You can then create these programmatically and add them to a parent horizontal `LinearLayout`.

If you however choose to go full custom, Youll have to handle measuring, layouting and drawing of all the components including the text above and below the line.

Take a look at [this link](https://realm.io/news/360andev-huyen-tue-dao-measure-layout-draw-repeat-custom-views-and-viewgroups-android/) for a good introduction to custom views on android

Comment: hey.. I have try to create custom view but I am not able get. Can you help with it. I have added java and xml file

Comment: Hey @AnkurKhandelwal, Glad you fixed it.